# How to skip an action and move on if one value in the array is empty in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

So, I have an array that is being populated by Gravity Forms in WordPress. The form works in such a way that certain fields are populated and others not based on conditional logic.

```
    $add_client_ukdir_one_payload = array(
    "cli_id" => $clientId,
    "ctcfirstname" => rgar( $entry, '418.3' ),
    "ctcmiddlename" => rgar( $entry, '418.4' ),
    "ctcjobtitle" => "Director",
    "ctclastname" => rgar( $entry, '418.6' ),
    "ctcAddress1" => rgar( $entry, '423.1' ),
    "ctcAddress2" => rgar( $entry, '423.2' ),
    "ctccity" => rgar( $entry, '423.3' ),
    "ctccountry" => rgar( $entry, '420' ),
    "ctcdateofbirth" => rgar( $entry, '421' ),
    "ctcemail" => rgar( $entry, '422.2' ),
    "ctcmobilephone" => rgar( $entry, '531' ) . rgar( $entry, '533' ),
    "ctcnationality" => rgar( $entry, '420' ),
    "ctcpostcode" => rgar( $entry, '423.5' ),
    "ctctelephone" => rgar( $entry, '530' ) . rgar( $entry, '532' ),
    "ctctitle" => rgar( $entry, '418.2' ),
);
$add_client_response = $client->AddContact($add_client_ukdir_one_payload);
```

There are multiple actions after this one. I want to be able to skip the action $add_client_response = $client->AddContact($add_client_ukdir_one_payload); if "ctclastname" is empty indicating that the part of the form needed to populate this array was not filled in.

My PHP knowledge is not that up to scratch, I was thrown in the deep end with this project. I think there needs to be a foreach or isset command, but I don't know the correct syntax or the way to pull a single value from the array.

Thanks in advance all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!empty($add_client_ukdir_one_payload['ctclastname'])) {
    $add_client_response = $client->AddContact($add_client_ukdir_one_payload);
}
```

Just do this.

Comment: Thanks! Tested and it is working like a dream! I knew there was a simple solution, just wasn't seeing it... been stuck on this file for 3 weeks now